# Distinct Group of Integer

Tags: python, algorithm, arraylist

Given an array of integers, I want to determine the number of distinct groups of integers wherein the values ascend.

Given array `myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2]`

There are 4 distinct groups of integers wherein the values ascend. i.e.

`[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2]` and `[2]`

Can some with experience guide me on how to achieve this in python?

Comment: What's the logic of there is `[2]` instead `[1,4]` in the result?

Comment: This is more of an algorithm problem than it is a Python problem. Also, why is `[1, 4]` not counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
group = []
list_of_groups = []
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2]
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if i == len(myList)-1:
        if len(group) > 0:
            group.append(myList[i])
            list_of_groups.append(group)
    else:
        if myList[i] <= myList[i+1]:
            group.append(myList[i])
        else:
            group.append(myList[i])
            if len(group) > 1:
                list_of_groups.append(group) 
            group = []
print(list_of_groups)
```

Result with different test cases -

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2]
Output: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4]

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5]
Output: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4, 5]]

myList = [1, 2]
Output: [[1, 2]]

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Output: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]

myList = [5, 2, 3, 4]
Output: [[2, 3, 4]]

myList = [5, 2]
Output: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer (also assuming [1, 4] is supposed to be there instead of [2]):

```
In [14]: def find_ascending_groups(my_list): 
    ...:     groups = [] 
    ...:     current_group = [my_list[0]]
    ...:     for i in range(1, len(my_list)):         
    ...:         if current_group[-1] <= my_list[i]: 
    ...:             current_group.append(my_list[i]) 
    ...:         else: 
    ...:             if len(current_group) > 1: 
    ...:                 groups.append(current_group) 
    ...:             current_group = [my_list[i]] 
    ...:     if len(current_group) > 1:
    ...:         groups.append(current_group) 
    ...:     print(groups) 
    ...:     

In [15]: find_ascending_groups(myList)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4]]
```

Comment: There is a minor bug in this solution. It fails for the input `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `[1, 4]` is supposed to be there instead of `[2]`, you can do something like this:

```
n [48]: ascending_ints = [] 
...: t = [] 
...: start_idx = 0 
...: while start_idx < len(myList) - 1: 
...:     first = True 
...:     for end_idx in range(start_idx + 1, len(myList), 1): 
...:         if myList[end_idx] >= myList[start_idx]: 
...:             if first: 
...:                 t.append(myList[start_idx]) 
...:                 first = False 
...:             t.append(myList[end_idx]) 
...:         else: 
...:             if t: 
...:                 ascending_ints.append(t) 
...:             t = [] 
...:             start_idx = end_idx 
...:             break     
...:         start_idx += 1 
...:                                                                        

In [49]: ascending_ints                                                         
Out[49]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4]]
```

This just makes the `start_idx` start at 0, `end_idx` begin at 1 and increment both. If `myList[end_idx] >= myList[start_idx]` then it appends it to `t`. If it's the first time it's happened for this iteration, it needs to also include the value at `start_idx`. Once the condition is no longer true, check if anything is in `t`, if it is, append it to `ascending_ints`, reset `t`, set `start_idx` = `end_idx` and break the `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that is more efficient in Python.

```
def find_ascending_groups(l):
    groups = []
    last_ascending = (l[0] <= l[1])
    l.append(l[-1] - 1)  # Add an additional element to make sure the last group is appended
    start = 0
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
        is_ascending = (l[i - 1]  <= l[i])
        if is_ascending != last_ascending:
            if is_ascending:
                start = i - 1     # l[i - 1] is a local minimum, set group start
            else:
                groups.append(l[start:i])  # l[i - 1] is a local maximum, generate group
            last_ascending = is_ascending

    l.pop()  # Remove added element
    return groups
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
I wrote a small `split_when` function which was recently merged into the [`more-itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library. `split_when` takes an iterable and a function. The function takes all pairs of consecutive elements and returns whether the iterable should be splitted between those elements:

```
>>> myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2]
>>> import more_itertools
>>> list(more_itertools.split_when(myList, lambda x, y: x > y))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4], [2]]
#           4>3  3>2        3>1     2>1     4>2
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**
For the record, you can use a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), that is [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in Python:

```
>>> myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2]
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: acc[:-1] + [acc[-1]+[x]] if acc and x >= acc[-1][-1] else acc + [[x]], myList, [])
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4], [2]]
```

Not very readable though, but if you write the lambda as a distinct function, you get a better idea of what's happening:

```
>>> def f(acc, x):
...     if acc: # there is at least one closed group
...         *prev, cur = acc # closed groups and current group
...         *_, y = cur # y is the last element of the current group
...         if x >= y: # if ascending
...             return prev + [cur + [x]] # return with x added to the current group
...
...     return acc + [[x]] # otherwise, return with x in a new group
...
>>> functools.reduce(f, myList, [])
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4], [2]]
```